# Can the tag [specfications] be spelt correctly

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are 7 questions in this tag, but it is not spelt correctly. It looks a bit illiterate at the moment. It should be spelt specifications, and probably does not need to be pluralised.

Comment: Standard for tags that can be pluralized is that they should be. But I'll correct the spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename complete: [specifications](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specifications)